# Adding Packages to Pycharm in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, package, permission-denied

I have installed Pycharm and I am trying to add packages through the project interpreter, but I get a permission denied error. I am not sure what the problem is, hope you can help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a virtual environment and install packages there. From the interpreter screen click on the gear icon; and select `Create VirtualEnv`.

See the [online help](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-virtual-environment.html) for more information.